# How to force ReadRegStr to read 32bit Node?

Tags: nsis

How to force NSIS read x32 tree of Uninstall registry key on x64 PC?
Tried everything.

```
SetRegView 32
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\XXX" "XXX"
```

Doesn't work. It reads

```
"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\XXX"
```

onInit, or other part of install, still nothing.

Used NSIS 3.03.

Answer (score 1):

The WOW6432Node key **is** the 32-bit key.

> [Redirected keys are mapped to physical locations under Wow6432Node](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx). For example, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software is redirected to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node. However, the physical location of redirected keys should be considered reserved by the system. Applications should not access a key's physical location directly, because this location may change. For more information, see Accessing an Alternate Registry View.

`SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\...` in RegEdit on a 64-bit machine is the 64-bit view and you need `SetRegView 64` to access it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit counter intuitive, but you need to use *64-bit* reg view instead.

To read from:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\XXX

Use the following line:

```
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM64 "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\XXX" "XXX"
```

or, you may use the following lines:

```
SetRegView 64
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\XXX" "XXX"
```